# I'm getting a big "oops" when clicking on the questions tab

Tags: bug, status-completed, navigation

[image]

Oddly enough, I'm only getting this when I click on the "questions" tab. I can open links to questions, go to "tags" page, successfully reach the home page by clicking on the logo etc.

I'm using Chrome version 44.0.2403.157 m, Win8 OS. (Reproduced on Firefox 39.0)

---

Just checked SO, SU & SF, and over 15 other SEs, beta or graduated. This seems to only happen on meta.SE; giving a "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)" and redirecting me to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/questions).

Comment: No repro, IE 6.  Open your console and add details from the network tag to an [edit].

Comment: @Won't you're not running IE6. .... ....right?

Comment: @Mat'sMug Wait, there's other *browsers* than IE6? Who knew.

Comment: Is this happening only on meta or other sites as well?

Comment: @AnnaLear I'm only getting it on MSE

Comment: Lol, same here. The last sentence on the error page asks as to report the problem on MSE, clicking the link brings me to... you know :D

Comment: Seems to only affect new-nav's "popular" tab. I'm looking further.

Comment: @Anna I'm not using the new-nav. (Thought the tags would demonstrate that)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I did some work earlier this week on switching avatars from HTTP default to HTTPS (inching ever so slowly towards SSL support here). Apparently we also already have some relative-protocol URLs for uploaded images in the DB, which is basically the problem here.

Fixed now - and we're gonna clean up the DB to normalize things later.